# redirect to last page user was on after login node.js and express (no passport)

Tags: node.js, express, express-session

I have a login button on a product detail page. If a user clicks on it they are redirected to the login page and after login I want to send them back to the product detail page.

In my starting point (app.js) I am setting a session variable for what I think is the referrer. (Should be like php $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI')

```
app.use((req, res, next) => {
    req.session.lastPageOn = req.get('Referrer');
    next();
});
```

In my login script I have:

```
if (req.session.lastPageOn) {
    res.redirect(req.session.lastPageOn)
} else {
    res.redirect('account/dashboard');
}
```

But every time I login in I get redirected to the login page as that was the last page I was on before logging in! So, it doesn't seem like `req.get('Referrer');` is the right thing to use or my implementation is incorrect.

UPDATE: I put in an if condition to not save the login page into the session but it feels like a hack. Is there not a better way?

```
if (req.originalUrl !== '/login') {
    req.session.lastPageOn = req.protocol + '://' + req.get('host') + req.originalUrl;
}
```

Comment: Maybe because the login page is still registered in the lastPageOn... You should do an exception if the page is `login` ....

Comment: Yeah, I did end up doing that like this: `if (req.originalUrl !== '/login') {
        req.session.lastPageOn = req.protocol + '://' + req.get('host') + req.originalUrl;
    }` but it feels a bit of a hack?

Comment: no because you really don't want to save the login path....

Comment: If you want it to feel less hacky, you can always create an array with `/login` in it, and any other pages you don't want to consider "lastPageOn", and then use `Array.includes` to check in the middleware. That way it's extensible and less hard-coded (still hard-coded, though). Regardless of how you define them, there are certain pages that shouldn't be considered "lastPageOn", and middleware intercepts *all* requests, so you'll have to do that check to skip them.